# Partial scaling of a composed elements in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am in the following situation: designing an interactive flow-chart GUI. I stuck with animating a scale down animation of the flow-chart. Composed elements of the flow-chart are minimized, but they keep being active.

I have something like this:

```
            <Canvas Canvas.Left="55" Canvas.Top="720" Height="100" Width="500" Tag="stepDown">
                <Line Stroke="#99CCFF" StrokeThickness="8" X1="0" X2="720" Y1="10" Y2="10">
                <Polygon Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" Points="0,30 40,0 40,60" Canvas.Left="-20" Canvas.Top="-20" Fill="#99CCFF"></Polygon>
                <Polygon Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" Points="0,0 0,60 40,30" Canvas.Left="720" Canvas.Top="-20" Fill="#99CCFF"></Polygon>
                <Image Canvas.Left="-50" Canvas.Top="-70" Height="53" Name="image32" Source="img/outlet.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="30" Tag="relative" />
            </Canvas>
```

And I would like to shift the whole canvas and its elements to the left - no problem with **Translate Transform**. Furthermore I would like to scale down only the **Line**, no problem with **Scale Transform**.

But (!) at the same time, I want that the **Polygons** stick to the two line endings of the line. When scaling down only the line, the **Polygons**, at least one, floats away.

I don't know how to dock these elements or define them at a relative basis. It works fine with a scale down on the whole **Canvas**, but this changes the **Polygon** and **Images** as well.

Comment: you mean, make (just) the line shorter and having all the sticked box getting closer ?

Comment: @Felice-pollano Yes, but the boxes/polygons have to be aligned automatically to the line ends.

Comment: posted some ideas in the reply.

Comment: Looks like you accepted Felice's answer. Could you elaborate more on your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to me you have to define hanchors points, as attached properties. Even define a behavior that track these points accordingly to poligon placements. Then you can bind these property to the line start/end point. In this way line should stay gripped to the polygons. But I did'nt try, is just a design idea.